# draw edge from node to edge in graphviz

Tags: graphviz

Is it possible to draw an edge from a Node to the center of an existing Edge in graphviz? I would like to duplicate this type of reaction diagram, common in chemical or biological networks.

[image: Desired Edge from Node-to-Edge]

Thanks!

--Peter

Comment: Can you please share the code of the following example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use invisible nodes, like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374108/graphviz-node-placement-and-rankdir) for instance.

Then play with creating subgraphs for A and B where

```
rank=same
```

and then an edge where

```
constraint=false
```

for the connection from C to the invisible node. This will put the first two above C.