# edges not obeying port specifications in DOT file

Tags: uml, graphviz

I'm trying to generate class diagrams for a tool I'm writing, however I can't seem to get the layout correct.

Here's my sample dot file generated from real data:

```
digraph G {
    fontname = "Bitstream Vera Sans"
    fontsize = 8
    splines = "ortho"

    node [
        fontname = "Bitstream Vera Sans"
        fontsize = 8
        shape = "record"
    ]

    edge[
        arrowtail="empty"
        dir="back"
    ]

    Baseclass [
        label = "{xxxxxxxxxx::Baseclass||+ xxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l}"
    ]

    SubclassOne [
        label = "{xxxxxxxxxx::SubclassOne||+ xxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l}"
    ]

    SubclassTwo [
        label = "{xxxxxxxxxx::SubclassTwo||+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l}"
    ]

    SubclassThree [
        label = "{xxxxxxxxxx::SubclassThree||+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l- xxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l}"
    ]

    SubclassFour [
        label = "{xxxxxxxxxx::SubclassFour||+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxx \l- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l}"
    ]

    SubclassFive [
        label = "{xxxxxxxxxx::SubclassFive||+ xxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxx \l+ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \l}"
    ]

    Baseclass:s -> SubclassOne:n;
    Baseclass:s -> SubclassTwo:n;
    Baseclass:s -> SubclassThree:n;
    Baseclass:s -> SubclassFour:n;
    Baseclass:s -> SubclassFive:n;
}
```

Which generates the following image using graphviz:
[image: Output of the given dot file]

I changed the order of the edge relationships to point from the base to the subclass (with a tail arrow) so that the subclass would be ordered higher vertically than the base classes.  Long method names are overflowing their containers, and the relationship edges aren't obeying the specified ports on the tail end.  It looks like their X position is correct, but the y possition is not.  I'd prefer it to look [something like this](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~kena/classes/6448/f08/_Media/homework1-2.png) where both the subclass relationship arrows are combined to form a single connection with the bottom center point in the superclass container.  If I remove the port specifications, the edges no longer clip into the nodes they connect, but the layout is still not what I'd consider ideal.

[image: Without explicit port specifications]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you figured out, and as mentioned on the [graphviz web site](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#asplines), `splines=ortho` does not work with ports:

> The value ortho specifies edges should be routed as polylines of axis-aligned segments. Currently, the routing does not handle ports or, in dot, edge labels.

If you have to use graphviz, you may consider adding additional nodes. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7374543/63733) contains an example using this technique.

Comment: That's unfortunate that they don't obey the correct port specifications, but invisible nodes don't seem too difficult to add in this circumstance